# Как исправить ошибку "недопустимый else без парного if"?

Tags: c++

Не могу разобраться, где накосячила.. Вроде синтаксис соблюден, прошу, спасайте.. Программа должна вычислить значение выражения, если возможно

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main () {
double x, y, R;
cout<<" x = ";
cin>>x;
cout<<" y = ";
cin>>y;
if (x!=3 || y!=-5){R =(x+y)/((x-3)*(y+5));} {cout<<" R =  "<<R<<"\n";} 
else {cout<<" Ошибка, деление на ноль ";}
system ("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: @brunetka, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Попробуйте ввести x=3 и y=100 или x=100 и y=-5. У вас условие неверное. Дизъюнкцию нужно заменить на конъюнкцию.

Answer (score 5):

```
if (x!=3 || y!=-5)
{
  R =(x+y)/((x-3)*(y+5));
} 
{
  cout<<" R =  "<<R<<"\n";
} 
else {
  cout<<" Ошибка, деление на ноль ";
}
```

Ну это же явно не валидное условие. Нужно убрать пару `}{`

```
if (x!=3 || y!=-5)
{
  R =(x+y)/((x-3)*(y+5));
  cout<<" R =  "<<R<<"\n";
} 
else {
  cout<<" Ошибка, деление на ноль ";
}
```

Comment: точно))) огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка в том, что у Вас формально две части then. Выбросив лишне, получим такое:

```
if (){} {} 
else {}
```

а это неверный синтаксис. Судя по коду, там просто нужно удалить `} {`. Удалив все лишнее, будет где-то так:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main () {
  double x, y, R;
  cout<<" x = ";
  cin>>x;
  cout<<" y = ";
  cin>>y;
  if (x!=3 || y!=-5) {
    R =(x+y)/((x-3)*(y+5));
    cout<<" R =  "<<R<<"\n";
  } 
  else {
    cout<<" Ошибка, деление на ноль ";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я так понимаю, в строке

```
if (x!=3 || y!=-5){R =(x+y)/((x-3)*(y+5));} {cout<<" R =  "<<R<<"\n";}
```

фигурные скобки } { посередине лишние.

P.S. Добрый совет: не ленитесь аккуратно форматировать код, тогда такие ошибки станут практически невозможны.